# How to move from Graffiti CMS to blogger?

Tags: blogger, blog

I currently use [Graffiti CMS](http://graffiticms.codeplex.com) for my blog. I am experiencing a lot of issues lately so I am thinking of moving to [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com).

How can I move all my posts from Graffiti CMS to Blogger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these two resources:

1. http://jeftek.com/520/migrating-blog-from-graffiticms-to-wordpress/
2. http://www.sagara.net/post/2009/08/29/GraffitiCMS-12-export-utility.aspx

They are not exactly what you are looking for, but it might help.

Comment: thanks, seams helpful i will go through these 2 resources and see if it can give me a way to migrate to blogger.